# Can I use Material 3 on Android version that is less than 12?

Tags: android, material3

Can I use Material 3 on Android version that is less than 12?

If I use Material 3 library for design and the user has an old phone with Android version less than 12, what he will get? Is it possible to launch an app with components from Material 3 library on Android less than 12?

Answer (score 0):

you cannot use given feature of material UI version 3 in below 12 android version.

1. Dynamic color
2. New widgets and components: Material 3 includes a number of new widgets and components, such as the OutlinedCard widget and the ChipGroup component.
3. New typography: Material 3 introduces a new typography system that is based on the Roboto font.
4. New animations: Material 3 includes a number of new animations, such as the elevation animation and the surface ripple animation.
5. Material 3 theme editor: This tool allows you to create custom Material 3 themes for your app.
6. Material 3 component builder: This tool allows you to create custom Material 3 components for your app.

Comment: did you use any generative AI at all in the writing of this answer post?

Comment: yes, i taken help using generative AI for fixed grammar.

Comment: please write your post yourself without using generative AI. see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/424036/11107541 and https://stackoverflow.com/help/ai-policy for the reason why

Comment: Thank you for the information. Next time, I won't use it.

Comment: please also edit _this post_ to be written in your own words without help from a generative AI. this is site policy. it's not optional.